# Explore XML-structure from R

Tags: r

I have some huge XML-files with information I need in R. The files are so big (4GB+) that xmlToList() runs forever without finishing. The 16GB RAM is enough. I work a lot with R but never before with XML. It is not HTML.

```
library(XML)
doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse("big_file.xml")  # Works fine
doc.list <- xmlToList(doc)  # Takes forever
test <- xpathApply(doc, "//parameter", xmlValue)  # Works fine, when I know the parameter name
```

If xmlToList() had worked, then I would have used names(), str(), summary(), doc.list[[1]][1], and so on to drill down into the data and learn the structure and what parameters are included. But with "doc" I'm not sure what to do.

Is there an R-way to split the "doc" into subtrees where  xmlToList() would work? Or a better way?